# removing element by tag name

Tags: javascript, removechild, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to remove an element by tag name using javascript. I set up a click handler for a button called "clear". I'm trying to use the function the function clear to remove all of the li elements from a list. This is what I have so far:

```
function clear() {
  var list = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (k = list.length; k >= 0; k++) {
    var parent = list.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(list[k]);
  }
}
```

Where "test" is the name of a ul element i have in the HTML. I'm getting a message in the console that parent is undefined. Any suggestions on how I need to modify the code so that I can delete the li elements?

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be that you’re starting at `list.length` and *incrementing* while `k >= 0`. Infinite loop.

Apart from that, you need to use `list[k].parentNode`, and you’re not declaring `k`, so:

```
function clear() {
  var list = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var k = list.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    var item = list[k];
    item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: this works for a list item that is part of the html. thanks. but, now I need to figure out how to delete such an item that I added dynamically to the page

Comment: @user2084813: It’ll work in the same way, as long as you added it in the same spot. Could you show your code to add an element dynamically, please?

Comment: thanks you already gave me everything I need. I just added a class name to the li where they were being added to the page and then i changed var list to equal the class name instead of using tag name

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, two small errors :

```
function clear() {
  var list = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var k = list.length; k-- > 0; ) { // decrement from list.length-1 to 0
    var parent = list[k].parentNode; // you need the parent of the item, not the list
    parent.removeChild(list[k]);
  }
}
```

Note that decrementing instead of incrementing is the thing to do as the opposite order would make you skip some items of the dynamic [nodelists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName).

Comment: that makes sense but i'm getting a message saying that list[k] is undefined

Comment: should start from `length - 1`

Comment: Also, nice global `k`, there.

Comment: @PaulS. Yeah, I saw the missing var too, but only by looking at minitech's answer and I didn't want to steal... but ok, let's put it ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize in somethig like that:

```
function clear(list) {
  for (var i = list.length, li; li = list[--i];)
    li.parentNode.removeChild(li);
}

clear(document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("li"));
```

Your main errors was `k++` instead of `k--` and `list.parentNode` instead of `list[k].parentNode` – `list` is a NodeList, doesn't have a parent; each element of the list can have a different parent.

Answer (score 0):

The [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList) returned by [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) is (usually) live (dynamic). This means that it's *length* decreases as nodes are removed. You must therefore consider this in your loop.
Here are some more examples of how to get around it.

```
function clear() {
    var nodes = document.getElementById("test").getElementsByTagName("li"),
        i = nodes.length; // one var statement at beginning
    // Choose one of
    while (i--) { // same as `i-->0`
        nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]); // remove nodes from end
    }
    // OR
    while (nodes.length) { // same as `nodes.length>0`, okay as dynamic list
        nodes[0].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[0]); // remove nodes from start
    }
    // OR
    for (; i >= 0; --i) {
        nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]); // remove nodes from end
    }
    // etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<ul id="test" type="bullet">
    <li>apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="Clearall()">Click me</button>
```

If your `UL` tag only contains the `LI` tag then try like below... It will help you..

```
function Clearall()
{
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="";
}
```

If your `UL` tag contains `LI` tag and other Tags then try like below.. It will help you..

**Javascript :**

```
function Clearall()
{
  var ul = document.getElementById("test");
  var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  while(lis.length > 0)
  {
   ul.removeChild(lis[lis.length - 1]);
  }
}
```